# why support vector must correspond to a positive alpha?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, svm

In solving Lagrangian Dual problem of Support Vector Machine, if `alpha>0`, we can infer that `yi(w.xi+b)-1=0` under KKT condition which says `alpha.(yi(w.xi+b-1)=0`. But on the reverse side, if `yi(w.xi+b)-1=0`, how can we know that the alpha correspond to it must be definitely positive?

Comment: The multiple notation can not be displayed. I use dot to indicate it in somewhere.

Comment: You can make code appear properly formatted by surrounding it with grave symbols (`) or by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. If you're asking why alpha is positive, this is a necessary condition for dual feasibility. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Necessary_conditions

Comment: @Nate The dual feasibility says alpha is less than or equal to 0. What I am asking is that:  if `xn` is a support vector, why the corresponding `an` must be definitely positive?

Comment: @oxguy3 Thank you for your advice.

Comment: My understanding is that in an SVM, the alphas corresponding to support vectors are all positive, and any alphas that are not support vectors are zero. Maybe you're using a different formulation of the problem than me. See the eq at the bottom of page 12 of Andrew Ng's notes here http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf

Comment: @Nate Yes, we do use the same formulation. I looked Andrew Ngs notes.  It told us the support vectors correspond to positive alpha, but it did not tell me why. See page 10 of the same note. In the middle of page 10, here is what the KKT dual complementarity condition says "Specifically, it implies that if `ai>0`, then `gi(w)=0`." But it did not guarantee on the other side which is " if `gi(w)=0`, then `ai>0`". The situation that `ai=0` while `gi(w)=0` seems acceptable by KKT condition.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that actually # of positive alpha is less than or equal to # of points lying on the margin.